# How can I add to the list of AllowableValues for a custom field in TFS 2010 programatically

Tags: c#, tfs, custom-fields

I have a process which synchronizes requirements and defects between a 3rd party tool and TFS 2010.

We would now like to extend the process a bit further to allow:

- Automatically adding new Area's and Iterations to a TFS project.
- Automatically adding new values to the list of AllowableValues for drop-down style custom fields.

I'm looking to do it programmatically via the TFS 2010 Client API in a .Net 3.5 class library project.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an area/iteration via code have a look at the sample code from [this post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2009/01/30/tfs-api-part-10-add-area-iteration-programmatically.aspx)
For the list values I'd suggest linking the drop down field to a global list and then updating the global list programmatically as shown in [this post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2010/03/08/tfs-api-part-23-create-global-list-xml-way.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the links, re: second option, found this info which was useful re: binding global list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404878(v=VS.100).aspx